# iOS - app store connect keep the removed app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I am new in iOS. A few days ago, I was try to create a new app on App Store Connect. Everything went smoothly and I created an app. I did not upload a build on it. The status is "Prepare for submission".

Because it is just an example for creating an app on App Store Connect, I remove my app.

I am able to remove the app by clicking on the "Remove App" button. However, the app keep staying in the App Store Connect with the status "Removed Apps".

Can someone tell me how can I remove the app permanently? The app keep my bundle ID and I cannot remove the App IDs in my Apple Developer Account too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am facing same issue and would like a solution.

Comment: @Covid19: I can't remove my app on App Store, it just keep appearing like that :( . Sorry I can't help you

Answer (score 1):

Once you delete your app from the Apple App Store, you will not be able to reuse the app name or SKU, and you will not be able to restore your app.

An alternative to deleting your app is simply removing it from sale on the Apple App Store. Once it is removed from sale, your app can no longer be downloaded from the Apple App Store. However, your app will remain in your iTunes connect account and you have the option in the future to update your app or restore it to the app store for sale. To remove your app from the Apple App Store, without deleting it, follow only steps 1-6 below.

**To delete your app from the Apple App Store:**

```
1) Log in to your iTunes Connect account. 

2) Click My Apps.
```

[image]

3) Select the app you want to delete.

[image]

4) Click Pricing.

[image]

5) If all territories were previously selected, click specific territories to display the list of all territories.

6) To remove your app from all App Store territories, click Deselect All and then click Save.

[image]

7) Your app status is changed to ../Art/status_red_2x.png Developer Removed From Sale.

8) To delete your app, click More and then click Delete App. [image]

9) To confirm, click Delete.

[image]

Reference: https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201709211-Delete-Your-App-from-the-Apple-App-Store

Comment: This is not the answer because he specifically said status was still "Prepare for submission". He did not submit the app. I am facing the same issue as him and you did not solve our issue at all.